# Winform not closing Why?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have some code to save a log in my FormClosing event that was working ok until I add code to create a Directory if it not exist such directory.

Now if I add the commented lines the application doesn't close.

I don't understand why.

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    TmrReporte.Stop()
    WriteRTBLog("Finalizacion del programa. - Version " & Me.ProductVersion, Color.Blue)
    Dim Fecha As String
    Fecha = Now.ToShortDateString & "-" & Now.ToLongTimeString
    Fecha = Fecha.Replace("/", "")
    Fecha = Fecha.Replace(":", "")
    Dim PathArchivo As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Logs\" & Fecha & ".logout"
    'If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(PathArchivo)) Then
    '    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(PathArchivo)
    'End If
    RTB_Log.SaveFile(PathArchivo, System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)    
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably an exception is being thrown

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-winforms-application-on-a

Comment: @HansPassant So in Windows x32 I will get an error but on Windows x64 don't? Interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the string format of the directory, you use `PathArchivo` for both the directory and the file while you actually only need to create the directory without filename for the directory creation:

```
Dim PathDir As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Logs" 'use only directory string here
Dim PathArchivo As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Logs\" & Fecha & ".logout" 'note that this is file name with .logout extension
If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(PathDir)) Then 'creates directory without .logout
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(PathDir)
End If
RTB_Log.SaveFile(PathArchivo, System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
```

Note that your `PathArchivo` is a file path with `logout` extension

Comment: Yes! You are right! So simple, I feel ashamed. I wonder Why I get no error?

Comment: Great, glad that it helps. Perhaps because it is actually allowed - a directory with dot `.` ;)